# moduleResolution: nodeNext "disables" the context menu of my chrome extension

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-chrome-extension, svelte, deepl

I am currently writing a personal chrome extension where I can translate text by highlighting it, right-clicking and translate it through the context menu.

I got the context menu working without the actual translation functionality.
When I started to implement said functionality using the deepl-node API however I got this error:

*"Cannot find module 'deepl-node'. Did you mean to set the 'moduleResolution' option to 'nodenext', or to add aliases to the 'paths' option? ts(2792)"*

Therefore I changed my module in tsconfig.json from ESNext to NodeNext and also added the moduleResolution statement and set it to NodeNext aswell.

This solved my issue with the API however it removed my menu choice from the context menu. I don't know why and can't find any explanation online.

Here's my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "module": "NodeNext",
    "moduleResolution":"NodeNext",
    "strict": true,

  },
  "include": ["public/background.ts"],
}
```

Here's my background.js

```
import * as deepl from 'deepl-node';
const authKey = "censored"; //REMEMBER TO HIDE
const translator = new deepl.Translator(authKey);

chrome.contextMenus.create({
    id: "1",
    title: "Translate \"%s\"",
    contexts: ["selection"],
});

console.log("Context menus created yo!");
// Store the tab ID of the newly created tab
let newTabId = null;
// Listen for the creation of a new tab
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener((tab) => {
    // Update the newTabId variable when a new tab is created
    newTabId = tab.id;
});

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener((info, tab) => {
    if (info.menuItemId === "1") {
        // Perform the fake translation logic
        const toTranslate = info.selectionText;
        const translatedText = Translate(toTranslate);
        // Now, open a new tab
        chrome.tabs.create({
            url: chrome.runtime.getURL("index.html"),
            active: true,
        });
        // Wait for the new tab to be created and then send the message to it
        const checkNewTabInterval = setInterval(() => {
            if (newTabId !== null) {
                // Send the message to the new tab using the unique task ID
                chrome.tabs.sendMessage(newTabId, { action: "updateTranslation", text: translatedText, taskId: newTabId }, () => {
                    // Callback function, executed once the message is sent
                    console.log("Message sent!");
                });
                // Clear the interval as the message has been sent
                clearInterval(checkNewTabInterval);
            }
        }, 100); // Adjust the interval as needed
    }
});

function Translate(TextToTranslate) {
    
    const translation = translator.translateText(TextToTranslate, null, 'es'); //Null means source language will be autodetected
    
    return translation;
}
```

Comment: Check errors for your extension in chrome://extensions page. If there are none, use devtools to set breakpoints and debug the code.

Comment: Not sure about the solution but if you've changed the module option, you've just changed how importing works and it's possible that the code broke on import or when using the import (because it may be undefined). Try using require instead of import in case that package is treated as a CJS module now.